# Validate Date Values in NVarchar field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have a reporting application written against some 3rd party software.  Unfortunately it stores all values as nvarchar and does not validate data entry on the client side as a result I am getting the following error when

```
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"  
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
```

or if I try to execute the code in SSMS:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure settlement_list, Line 10
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I assume this is the result of someone entering a text value in the data field so I've tried this ISDATE code to find the bad value:

```
   SELECT mat3_02_01, CONVERT(datetime, mat3_04_02), mat3_04_02 FROM lntmu11.matter3
   WHERE ISDATE(mat3_04_02) <> 1
   AND Coalesce(mat3_04_02, '') <> ''
   order by mat3_04_02 desc
```

and I get zero row returned ... I also manually sifted through the data (its sveral 100 thousand rows so its kind of hard and see no bad values ???

Does anyone have any suggestions ?

EDIT ---

Here is the stored proc (I know where clause is ugly)

```
SELECT mat_no, 'index'=matter.mat1_01_06,
  'insurance'=Replace(Replace(matter.mat1_03_01, 'INSURANCE COMPANY', ' '), 'COMPANY', ''), 
  matter.[status], 'casestage'=mat1_04_01, 'injured'=matter.MAT1_01_07, matter.client,
 'terms'=mat3_04_06, 'ClmAmt'=matter.mat1_07_01, 
  'ClmBal'=matter.mat1_07_03, 'SetTot'=matter3.MAT3_04_09, 'By'=mat3_03_02,
  'DtSttld'=mat3_04_02, 'SettlStg'=(MAT3_06_08 + ' / ' + MAT3_06_05)
FROM [lntmu11].matter3 inner join 
[lntmu11].matter ON [lntmu11].matter.sysid = [lntmu11].matter3.sysid
WHERE
(DateDiff(month, convert(datetime, MAT3_04_02, 101), GETDATE()) = @range 
  and mat3_03_02 like @by)
or
(mat3_04_06 like @by2 
  and DateDiff(month, convert(datetime, MAT3_04_02, 101),  GETDATE()) = @range) 
ORDER BY MAT3_03_02
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "MSSQL" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Examine the query where  

      ISDATE(mat3_04_02) = 1 
      AND 
      Coalesce(mat3_04_02, '') = ''

Doesn't Coalesce(mat3_04_02, '') = '' only match a null?

It canNOT be both a date and null.

Comment: @Blam that's a good point... when I was editing my post I originally had a comment next to that `-- shouldn't this be IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: Don't use `'single quotes'` for aliases. Use `[square brackets]` or `"double quotes"`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force the order the query engine will try to process the statement without first dumping the `ISDATE() = 1` rows into a #temp table. You can't guarantee the processing order or short circuiting, even though some will suggest using a CTE or subquery to filter out the bad rows first. So some might suggest:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT mat3_02_01, mat3_04_02
  FROM Intmu11.matter3
  WHERE ISDATE(mat3_04_02) = 1
  AND mat3_04_02 IS NOT NULL -- edited!
)
SELECT mat3_02_01, CONVERT(DATETIME, mat3_04_02), mat3_04_02
FROM x
ORDER BY mat3_04_02 DESC;
```

And this may even appear to work, today. But in the long term, really the only way to guarantee this processing order - in current versions of SQL Server - is:

```
SELECT mat3_02_01, mat3_04_02
  INTO #x
  FROM Intmu11.matter3
  WHERE ISDATE(mat3_04_02) = 1
  AND mat3_04_02 IS NOT NULL; -- edited!

SELECT mat3_02_01, CONVERT(DATETIME, mat3_04_02), mat3_04_02
  FROM #x
  ORDER BY mat3_04_02 DESC;
```

Have you thought about validating the values on input? For example, you can change where this error appears in the application by slapping them on the wrist when they enter an invalid date, instead of punishing the person who selects their bad data. If you are controlling the update/insert via a stored procedure, you can say:

```
IF ISDATE(@mat3_04_02) = 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Please enter a valid date.', 11, 1);
    RETURN;
END
```

If you aren't controlling data manipulation via stored procedure(s), then you can add a check constraint to the table (after you've cleaned up the existing bad data).

```
UPDATE Intmu11.matter3 SET mat3_04_02 = NULL
  WHERE ISDATE(mat3_04_02) = 0;

ALTER TABLE Intmu11 WITH NOCHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT mat3_04_02_valid_date CHECK (ISDATE(mat3_04_02)=1);
```

This way when the error message gets bubbled up to the user they will see the constraint name and hopefully will be able to map that to the data entry point on the front end that failed:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>  The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the CHECK constraint "mat3_04_02_valid_date". The conflict
>   occurred in database "your_db", table "Intmu11.matter3", column
>   'mat3_04_02'.
>  The statement has been terminated.

Or better yet, use the right data type in the first place! Again, after updating the existing bad data to be `NULL`, you can say:

```
ALTER TABLE Intmu11.matter3 ALTER COLUMN mat3_04_02 DATETIME;
```

Now when someone tries to enter a non-date, they'll get the same error that the users are currently getting when they try to select the bad data:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>  Conversion failed when
>   converting date and/or time from character string.

In SQL Server 2012, you'll be able to get around this with [`TRY_CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993%28SQL.110%29.aspx) but you should still be trying to get the data type right from the beginning.

Comment: "Have you thought about validating the values on input?" Unfortunately its 3rd party software I have no access to source code ... Moving forward I was thinking of a task to clean out bad values if I can figure out the issue.  I tried both of these alterations and still have no rows ??? What am I missing here.

Comment: p.s. you are a SQL beast my friend

Comment: If you have zero rows, then it sounds like nobody has entered a valid date. This should further prove why you should fix the data type. The `WHERE` clause you have has filtered out the invalid dates (which seems to be all of the rows), but be very careful - with a different plan SQL Server may try to process the `CONVERT` *before* the filter.

Comment: Or @Blam is right. Your `WHERE` clause is saying `WHERE ISDATE(col)=1 and col IS NULL` - should be `IS NOT NULL`, or not even there since it is redundant...

Comment: "No access to code or stored procs" ... so what CAN you change?

Comment: I have tried all variations and I can't find any invalid data.  Is there anything else that could be causing this error.  Theoretically just doing "SELECT CONVERT(datetime, mat3_04_02) FROM lntmu11.matter3" should throw an error if there was a invalid value, no ?  I feel like there is something else to this.

Comment: I can only change the values or add a trigger, I suppose ?  Its shitty vendor 3rd party legal software every field is nvarchar(max) including the pk's.

Comment: You're confusing me. Are you getting the error or aren't you?

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting the error when I execute the above stored procedure "SELECT mat_no, 'index'=matter.mat1_01_06, ..." I have fixed my code to find the bad values as you and Blam suggested and I find no invalid data in the column.  I have to assume its something else or I'm doing something wrong

Comment: What does this yield? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [lntmu11].matter3 WHERE ISDATE(MAT3_04_02) = 0;` Also what is the data type of `@range` and what is the value you're passing to it?

Comment: 502,359 but so does SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [lntmu11].matter3 WHERE (MAT3_04_02) = ''  ??? @range param = 0

Comment: So your question is pretty fractured now. Can you re-write it to explain your actual stored procedure, what results you expect with all of these rows where `MAT3_04_02 = ''`, and what `@range` is (both type and actual value). I might even suggest a new question because this one has become a mess.

Comment: Yes I have to leave but when I get home later I will re-ask the question in a more coherent fashion.  Thank you guys for all your help troubleshooting

Answer (score 3):

Examine the query where

```
  ISDATE(mat3_04_02) = 1 
  AND 
  Coalesce(mat3_04_02, '') = ''
```

To be a date it must have a value. 
But is only matches the second condition if it has not value. 
The intersection (and) of those two conditions is always false.

If you are looking for null then "mat3_04_02 is null" but it still will return 0 rows.

Try

```
   SELECT mat3_02_01, CONVERT(datetime, mat3_04_02), mat3_04_02 
   FROM lntmu11.matter3
   WHERE ISDATE(mat3_04_02) = 1
   order by CONVERT(datetime, mat3_04_02) desc
```

I think you would want date sorted and not string sorted

The question started as finding valid dates and it morphed into finding invalid dates

```
   SELECT mat3_02_01, mat3_04_02 
   FROM lntmu11.matter3
   WHERE ISDATE(mat3_04_02) = 0 
   AND mat3_04_02 is not null
   order by mat3_04_02) desc
```

Comment: Try : I've tried this and it returns me the valid date rows ? if I try ISDATE(..) = 0 I get couple 100,000 empty rows but no bad text data ??

Comment: The original question was to find valid date.  How can you expect someone following this question to understand what is going on?  How can you expect CONVERT(datetime, mat3_04_02) to succeed for invalid dates.?

Comment: I agree I'm just rather frustrated : (